# Get nodes of a particular content type attached to a group

Tags: organic-groups

I want all the nodes of content type 'Site Address' attached to a group. I have written the following code. It doesn't seem to work.

```
$gid=$form_state['values']['group_id']; 
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->condition('n.status', 1, '=')
        ->condition('n.type','site_address','=')
        ->fields('n', array('nid')); 
$query->join('og_membership', 'ogm', "ogm.gid = :gid AND n.nid = ogm.etid AND ogm.entity_type = 'node'  ", array(':gid' => $gid));   $result=$query->execute()->fetchAll();

dpm($result);
```

Comment: mistake in query  AND n.nid = ogm.entity_id

Comment: There is no column named 'entity_id' in 'og_membership' table.